# Why name does not exist in current context?

Tags: c#

My method

```
            await ctx.HttpRequestAsync("cancel build", async (http, log) =>
            {
                var response = await http
        .Patch($"{host}/v0.1/apps/{userName}/{appName}/builds/{buildId}")
        .SetXApiTokenHeader(xApiToken)
        .SetCustomHeader("diagnostic-context", diagnosticContext)
        .SetCustomHeader("internal-request-source", internalRequestSource)
        .SendAndReceiveAsJsonAsync<BuildCreateModel>();
```

Class BuildCreateModel

```
 public string sourceVersion { get; set; }
```

But Intelisense shows error

```
int.TryParse(jsonData.sourceVersion, out sourceVersion)
```

It says that
[image]

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: public string sourceVersion and you are tryParsing an int into it, seems a little weird to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass a property as a reference variable.

Rewrite the code to something like this:

```
if(int.TryParse(jsonData.sourceVersion, out var sv))
{
  sourceVersion = sv;
}
```